# Adding Ciphers to Server 2012 R2

Tags: ssl, cipher

I need to add the following Ciphers to my server:

> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256

> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

I found the following article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/manage-tls

However, it's not too clear to me.
The list I get from the "SSL Cipher Suites" field contains 39+ Ciphers and is A LOT longer than the allowed 1023 characters. While in actuality when I test my explorer11 browser against ssllabs I get only 16.

Comment: Applies to: Windows Server (Semi-Annual Channel), Windows Server 2016, Windows 10 means your out of scope with 2012

Comment: If the list is longer than 1023 characters, group policy cannot be used to manage this setting. Check the value in the registry, and also using a tool like IISCrypto will show you the current registry values.

Comment: +1 for IISCrypto - just manage your TLS settings with this.